# Smoothing train/test data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, outliers

I am currently working on time series forecasting. I know that the first step is to divide the time series into train and test. Then I also understand that I have to normalize the test set using the training normalization parameters.

However, I would like to apply a kind of smoothing by moving averages and eliminate those values that are farther away from $mean \pm 1.5*std$ (the outlier values), but I don't know how it could transfer this smoothing into test data.

- Can the outliers be removed based on the test data only?
- The smoothing of moving averages is not possible to use, so I have to use the mean and std of the whole train set to eliminate the outliers of the test data?

If you have any other approach on how to eliminate outliers in the test data to improve forecasting is appreciated.

Comment: Removing outliers in the *test* data does not "improve forecasting". What it does is modify the task at hand to make it easier in an unrealistic way. It's cheating; you can't prevent outliers from happening in real life. Removing them in the training data is an entirely different matter.

Comment: Sorry  @ChrisHaug I think I have explained it wrong.If my predictors are $y_{1},..., y_{t}$ and my target value is  $y_{t+1}$, I want to remove the extreme values from the train dataset from the predictors and the target. However, I know that from the test target value I can not remove them but I would like to remove them from the predictors. Although you can not remove the outliers form real data, I understand that they are a minority on the data and they add a lot of noise to the forecasting  model.